# how to render html tag as string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string, escaping

I'm working on a project that is developed with C#, and my knowledge of C# isn't extensive, I just started to learn a few days ago :)

I came across this function :

```
public static IHtmlString RenderEditData<T>(string linkText) where T : CorinaEntity
{
    string id = new IdGenerator().Generate<T>();

    return new HtmlString(String.Format("<a href=\"#\" data-corina='{{ \"id\" : \"{0}\", \"clrType\" : \"{1}\" }}'>{2}</a>", id, typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName, linkText));
}
```

The above returns me a link tag, which was fine when I first started working on the project, but now I just need the `data` attribute output as a string. So I just tried this :

```
public static String RenderEditData<T>() where T : CorinaEntity
{
    string id = new IdGenerator().Generate<T>();


return String.Format("data-corina='{{ id : \'{0}\', 'clrType' : \'{1}\' }}", id, typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName);
}
```

The thing is that instead of resulting in this :

```
data-corina="{ "id" : "-[Model.Content]", "clrType" : "Model.Content, Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" }"
```

It returns something like this :

```
data-corina="'{" id="" :="" &#39;-[model.content]&#39;,="" &#39;clrtype&#39;="" &#39;model.content,="" model,="" version="1.0.0.0," culture="neutral," publickeytoken="null'" }=""
```

Obviously, there's some string escaping that I'm doing wrong, but I have no clue how to do it and not mess up the variables I need there. Can someone point me to the right solution for this ? Also am I doing it wrong if I changed `public static IHtmlString RenderEditData` to `public static String RenderEditData`, if the result I want is just a string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Html.Raw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) helper to output raw HTML.

Alternatively, wrap the string in an `HtmlString`:

```
public static String RenderEditData<T>() where T : CorinaEntity
{
    string id = new IdGenerator().Generate<T>();

    return new HtmlString(
           string.Format("data-corina='{{ id : \'{0}\', 'clrType' : \'{1}\' }}", 
                                        id, 
                                        typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName));
}
```

Comment: I still get a weird result and nothing like what I first got when it was a tag

Comment: I don't quite know what "weird result" means, @Roland

Comment: There were some quotes in places that weren't supposed to be, but I just figured that I missed the wrapping quotes around the whole object: `"data-corina='{{ \"id\" : \"{0}\", \"clrType\" : \"{1}\" }}'"` :)

Answer (score 0):

MVC will escape any plain string you return. That is why your original function returns an `IHtmlString`. When you return `HtmlString`, the pipeline knows that you definitely expect the result to contain raw HTML.